# Setting 'Language Profile' in Protege 5.2 preferences

Tags: settings, owl, protege

I want to set OWL language to **OWL-Full** in Protege, but cannot find the setting in the Preferences window in Protege 5.2 that I'm using.

[image]

Googling shows that the older versions had the option:

[image]

Is it disabled in new versions of Protege? If so how can I use **OWL-Full** within Protege?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Protege4Migration#Side_by_Side_Comparison:

> No OWL Full

Since version 4, Protégé is not an RDF editor, whereas OWL Full is, [roughly speaking](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/#Semantics), RDF with OWL vocabulary.

Also, there is no OWL 2 Full "[profile](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/#Semantics)" in OWL 2.

Possibly all you need is [OWL punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning), which is in OWL 2 DL.